How to keep my local feature branch code while up to date with remote github master branch?
Say I have a master branch in github. I raise a PR (my feature branch is in my local machine), got merged, get ready for next release.
Then I found out we have another priority release, then we revert my PR (back to original master branch state). The priority release PR will come soon.
Now in my local machine, if I git pull from master branch (remote github) to my local feature branch, all my local branch code will be gone.
How do I keep my feature code while still keep up to date with master branch from github?

You could merge the last commit of the master branch before the revert. (I should add, this is not a good workflow; if there is a hotfix for a priority release it should have been on a branch of its own.)

The premise of this question basically boils down to "How can I re-merge my feature after it was reverted?"
The two basic options are:

Change the commit IDs of your feature so they can be brought in again. Either use cherry-pick like in eftshift0's answer, or an alternate syntax is with git rebase --no-ff X~4 which will force rebase to rewrite the IDs instead of fast-forwarding. (This is the same as cherry-picking.)
My personal preference is to Revert the Revert. For example, checkout your feature branch, then update it using any of these which will have the identical effect:

git fetch
git switch my-feature

git merge origin/master
# OR
git rebase origin/master
# OR
git reset --hard origin/master


Note that you don't really need your feature branch anymore since it was already merged. Maybe you even deleted it after your PR into master was completed. If so you could just create a new feature branch starting from origin/master. Regardless of whether you use the old feature branch name or a new one:

Now, find the commit ID that was reverted (let's call it abcd1234) and revert it:
git revert abcd1234

In older Git versions this will create a commit message "Revert 'Revert PR 123...'" but in newer versions it now shows "Reapply 'PR 123 ...'". You can now merge this into master to bring your changes back in.

Recreate your feature branch so that git thinks that the branch has not been merged ever..... Suppose that the feature branch is X and its work is 4 commits:
git checkout X~4
git cherry-pick HEAD..X

At this point you have the exact same work you had before but to git, this has not been merged (these are different commits from the original 4). If you like it, place X over here and I would suggest to rebase:
git checkout -B X
git rebase origin/master


You should avoid running git pull directly on your feature branch to keep it clean. Keep your feature branch isolated till the priority release PR is merged to the master.
Follow these steps to keep your feature branch synced with the master along with your changes:
Step 1: Update your local master branch with the changes in the remote master
git checkout master
git pull origin master

Step 2: Rebase the feature branch onto the master
git checkout <Your Feature Branch>
git rebase origin/master

If any conflicts, resolve them and continue the rebase process with
git rebase --continue

With these steps your feature branch changes will stay on top of the latest master commits.
Once the rebase is complete push the updated feature branch to the remote with the force flag -f. The force flag is required when you rebase.
git push origin <your-feature-branch> -f


The Step 2 "description" is backwards. Also, won't the rebase just fast-forward?

@TTT yes, you are right. The description in the step 2 should be backward. I have updated the description.
about the question "won't the rebase just fast-forward?"
As far as I know rebase does not fast-forward like the traditional merge(which is git merge without the option --no-ff). rebase will show the history of the commit branches. when the feature branch is merged to master(non fast forward) you should see the non linear history with the commit branches.

Take a look at this documentation to understand what I mean by "fast-foward" in the context of a rebase.

Anyway, my point is that at the moment of your rebase command, the feature branch has already been merged into master, so it won't actually do anything, except "fast-foward" up to the tip of master. I just added an answer with more details which shows that git merge origin/master, and git rebase origin/master, and even git reset --hard origin/master would all be identical in this case.
